# Dynamic form control for address(country, state, district and place)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am adding dynamic form control on dropdown change, I am able to add but getting error and also not able to get the value in formName.value,

I am getting error

Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'countryName'

My code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFormControlsFields(Object.keys(this.countryKey)[0]);
  }

  getFormControlsFields(field: string) {
    const formGroupFields: any = {};
    formGroupFields[field] = new FormControl('');
    this.formFields.indexOf(field) === -1 && this.formFields.push(field);
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup(formGroupFields);
  }
  
  handleChange(value: any, type: string) {
    if (type === 'countryName') {
      this.getFormControlsFields(Object.keys(this.countryKey.states.s1)[0]);
      this.removeFormControls(['districtName', 'placeName']);
      this.fieldValues = {
        ...this.fieldValues,
        stateName: this.getFilteredList(secondLevelArr, value)
      };
    }
  }
```

Below is my HTML code

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div *ngFor="let field of formFields">
                <mat-form-field *ngIf="field" appearance="fill" class="w-100-per">
                    <mat-label>{{field | titlecase}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-select [formControlName]="field" (selectionChange)="handleChange($event.value, field)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let value of fieldValues[field]" [value]="value.id">{{value.name}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add control with "addControl":

```
this.contactForm.addControl(
  'countryName',
  new FormControl(
    '', // yourFirsState
    Validators.required))
```

In annother hand you can retrive the control with:

```
const nameControl = this.contactForm.get('countryName');
```

or:

```
this.contactForm.controls['countryName'].value
```

Before you if() print the value of your form with:

```
this.form.controls
```

This code will give to you very good info about the status of your form